# Should I use "tournament", "championship" or simply "game" for an online competiion site?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

We're releasing a website in which the users can submit and join video game competitions. The game can be League of Legends, FIFA, Counter Strike and so forth.

We're not native english speakers so we're not sure whether we should use "tournament", "championship" or simply "game" to characterize an instance of these competitions.

What is the difference between these terms? Which of them would be more suitable for one single instance of an eletronic sport competition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because April Fools.

Answer (score 1):

A 'tournament' is a competition in which competitors are placed into 1-on-1 rounds, and compete to get into higher divisions. The end result will be a 1-on-1 with the two teams that got the furthest.

A 'championship' is a competition in which teams can win and lose without too much concern, and the team that wins is the one that has won the most games. In the result of a tie, these two will play against each other for first place.

'Game' is a lot more general a term, but can be used if tournament and championship don't quite work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any term that is short and generic for "tournament" and "championship" that is better than "game"? Because game could be confused with a game title

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple rounds in which the weaker competitors are gradually eliminated, this process can be called  **playoffs**, with the final round, sometimes called a **championship round**, determining the ultimate winner.    Usually these championships use such terms as **quarter-finals, semi-finals, finals** for the last few rounds. Others may use more colorful language....

See, for example **NCAA Basketball championship**.  For this, the NCAA uses "brackets" to diagram the pairings for each game and to show which teams continue to the next round. Here are this year's brackets (incomplete, as the tournament is still in progress—the brackets progress from *left AND  right* toward the *center*).
http://www.ncaa.com/interactive-bracket/basketball-men/d1

A single instance of competition should be called a **game** or a **match** (although in tennis, a "match" consists of many "sets", each of which includes several games!)

So if the same two competitors play multiple consecutive games against each other, to determinine which team moves on, you could call each duch series of games a **set** or a **match**.

If various members of the same team compete in various types of **events** (in your case, various game types?), with their combined performance making up the **team score**, this is more like a **track meet**.  There would be no playoffs or brackets; just a final ranking of all teams' total scores.